# S6: Folder is empty when trying to view the files on PC, display broken

Tags: storage

So my phones display recently died and trying to view it on my PC leaves me with an empty folder...
The phone is still on and running though, only the display is broke
There are different solutions to this, I link them below:

[Galaxy S6 Folder is Empty on PC](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148350/galaxy-s6-folder-is-empty-on-pc/161247#161247?newreg=5cf19f7476f9436d82252af8d0688664)

There must be a way to operate the phone from my PC, right?

Would be happy if someone could help

Comment: S6 supports no MHL but OTG, connect keyboard and press space + pin + enter to unlock, this should bring up your files. if you have pattern, set temporary lock screen pin from https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager (secure device)

Comment: untested, but if it works you can use scrcpy to fully remote control your device from usb-debugging https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159551